# Ember Data: saving polymorphic relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble saving "hasMany" polymorphic records in Ember Data (1.0.0-beta.15). It looks as if Ember Data isn't setting the "type" property of the polymorphic relationship. Relationships in serialized records look like:

```
"roles": ["1", "2"]
```

When I expect them to look more like:

```
"roles":[{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "professionalRole"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "personalRole"
  }
];
```

I see the following error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

If the records come back from the server in the expected format, all is well. The error only occurs when Ember Data creates the relationship.

I experience this using the FixtureAdapter, LocalStorageAdapter, and the RESTAdapter. I've read every piece of documentation I can find on the subject, but I cannot see my mistake.

I've created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/AndrewBird81/pen/emjWee) to demonstrate the problem, but I'll also paste that code below.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  roles: DS.hasMany('role')
});

App.Role = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  person: DS.belongsTo('person', {
    polymorphic: true
  })
});

App.ProfessionalRole = App.Role.extend({
  rank: DS.attr()
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    var person = this.store.createRecord('person', {
      name: 'James'
    });
    var role = this.store.createRecord('professionalRole', {
      title: 'Code Reviewer',
      rank: 'Expert'
    });
    var promises = Ember.RSVP.hash({
      person: person.save(),
      role: role.save()
    });
    promises.catch(function() {
      controller.set('initialSaveResult', 'Failure');
    });
    promises.then(function(resolved) {
      controller.set('initialSaveResult', 'Success!');
      var resolvedPerson = resolved.person;
      var resolvedRole = resolved.role;

      // Either/both of these break it
      //resolvedRole.set('person', resolvedPerson);
      resolvedPerson.get('roles').addObject(resolvedRole);

      var innerPromises = Ember.RSVP.hash({
        person: resolvedPerson.save(),
        role: resolvedRole.save()
      });
      innerPromises.catch(function() {
        controller.set('secondSaveResult', 'Failure');
      });
      innerPromises.then(function() {
        controller.set('secondSaveResult', 'Success!');
      });
    });
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  initialSaveResult: "Loading...",
  secondSaveResult: "Loading..."
});
```

Comment: You're best advised to skip using Ember Data's half-baked polymorphism support altogether. It really is useless except for some very narrow use cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517764/ember-data-polymorphic-relationships/28553824#28553824.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo, that's actually the route I've taken. Using a combination of regular relationships and and a computed property to aggregate them together works fairly well. To be honest, I've spent so much time researching this that I'm convinced it's a bug in Ember Data. If no one here can point out the err of my ways, I'll report it.

Comment: I am also getting this error for last few weeks. But in ember-cli generated projects setting `Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = false; ` in `app.js` works.

I've tried ember-data 0.12 to 0.15 , but no use... 0.16 has lots of breaking changes, hence not touching it.